# error while inserting values python mysql

Tags: python, mysql

everything syntax is right but still getting errors .how to fix this error ?

not inserting data due to syntax error

```
try:
    cur.execute('insert into test(PassengerId,SibSp,Parch,Embarked) values(892,0,0,'Q'),(893,1,0,'S'),(894,0,0,'Q'),(895,0,0,'S'),(896,1,1,'S')')
    print('data inserted successfully')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

error =

```
 cur.execute('insert into test(PassengerId,SibSp,Parch,Embarked) values(892,0,0,'Q'),(893,1,0,'S'),(894,0,0,'Q'),(895,0,0,'S'),(896,1,1,'S')')
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have using `'` to wrap the parameters,so you need to use `"` to wrap the sql itself

```
try:
    cur.execute("insert into test(PassengerId,SibSp,Parch,Embarked) values(892,0,0,'Q'),(893,1,0,'S'),(894,0,0,'Q'),(895,0,0,'S'),(896,1,1,'S')")
    print('data inserted successfully')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```